# VirtualHost always returns default host with Apache on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I try to setup a virtual host besides the default `localhost`. 
Whenever I try to call my virtual host `http://test` I get the default Apache2 Index file that sits in the directory of `http://localhost`. Furthermore apache returns this page still after disabling (`a2dissite`) both VirtualHost files an reloading apache (`service apache2 reload`).

What could go wrong that the virtual host is not working?

**Configuration:**

My directory structure is the following:

```
/var/www/html                  # Default localhost dir
/var/www/html7index.html       # Apache2 default index

/var/www/test                  # HTML dir for the virtual host
/var/www/test/index.html       # My "website"
```

Content of `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Laptop
127.0.0.1       test
```

Directory content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
000-default.conf
default-ssl.conf
test.conf
```

File `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

File `test.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost test:80>
        ServerAdmin test@localhost
        ServerName test
        NameVirtualHost test
        ServerAlias test
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So you already did `a2ensite test`?

Comment: yes, sure. Sorry, forgot that.

Comment: Your vHost file and hosts files doesn't look bad for me.. Are you getting the apache default page when doing _a2ensite test_ ? Are you able to find anything from logs ?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs. But I figured it out. See my own answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Call it with **sudo**: `sudo service apache2 reload`

---

Looks like the behaviour of `service apache2 reload` fooled me. See the following log:

```
user@Laptop:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo a2ensite test.conf 
Enabling site test.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
user@Laptop:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                  * 
user@Laptop:/etc/apache2/sites-available$
```

Try to reach `http://test`: **NOT working**

```
user@Laptop:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                  * 
user@Laptop:/etc/apache2/sites-available$
```

Try to reach `http://test`: **WORKING**

So, find the difference! The point is that I thought it would've reloaded correctly in the first place. There are no entries in the log files either. Calling it with **`sudo`** helped. Is this a bug?

Comment: Without sudo, apache throw no exception. So you don't know if you reloaded properly your conf. Thank you.

Comment: Clear browser cache too. I was being sent to my default site, which redirected me via the .htaccess there. This meant, even when I did use sudo my browser still decided to redirect me. Clearing cache fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for this, second that no error is thrown (!)

Answer (score 63):

I was facing this issue, and it turned out I had to disable the default virtual host.

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

---

#### Possible Expanation:

According to the apache documentation [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html):

> [...] If the main server has no ServerName at this point, then the hostname of the machine that httpd is running on is used instead.

That means if the default vhost (commonly 000-default.conf) has no ServerName set - *which is the default* - Apache will fallback to the hostname of the operating system.

As a result, Apache selects and serves from the default vhost (000-default.conf) even though another user-created vhost with the same ServerName as the machine's hostname is configured.

The reason is that Apache sorts the vhosts alphabetically by filename and chooses the first vhost configuration that matches the requested HTTP Host header. Thus, the 000-default.conf is checked before user-defined vhosts, as they are usually not prefixed with `000-`.

Comment: This has worked for me. But I hate to have solutions without explanation. Why isn't Apache following my virtual host and instead loading the default virtual host? Totally doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Please add some details about it.

Comment: Usually apache2 on Ubuntu has a virtual host setup for the default site, i.e. when apache can't find a more specific domain (TLD) attached to another virtual host.

The command `a2dissite SITE_NAME` is a script for disabling any enabled site on Ubuntu/Debian systems. The opposite command is `a2ensite` for enabling a disabled site.

These commands can only be executed with privileged rights, i.e. `sudo`. It also works with Ubuntu current 16.04LTS and 17.04.

Comment: worked for me. I think the damn * in the <virtual host> is the problem...

Comment: Nope. I have the reverse problem. I have <VirtualHost *:443> and it still is processing e.conf instead. This makes sense as e.conf is first alphabetically, but what baffles me is that it didn't stop ssl.conf from being processed first before I installed letsencrypt https://serverfault.com/questions/1013270/lets-encrypt-stopped-processing-ssl-conf-first

Comment: disabling/removing the 000-default.conf file did not solve the issue of the vhost not working correctly. What if you have multiple vhost files? Your solution is short sited because it will work, no doubt - but not as intended, which is to have a fully functioning vhost set up.

Answer (score 7):

Just pointing this out that may be obvious for experienced users, but not so much if you're a first timer.

Make sure that the config you're using in `/sites-enabled` ends with a `.conf` as expected in your `apache2.conf`

That was my problem and it fixed it.

Comment: Don't know how long I have looked at my code and not noticed that my nicely named files, are domains, not domain.conf. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 5):

If you have already tried the following:
1. Checked permissions of the document root and parent folder.
2. a2dissite 000-default etc.
3. Restarted apache with sudo service apache2 reload
 
And it is still not working then do the following:

**1. Enable debug logging:**

`vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

`LogLevel debug`

**2. Restart apache2 and monitor the logs**
`sudo service apache2 restart`

`tail -f /var/log/apache2/*.log`

**3. Notice if the IP of the server is showing in the logs as expected:**

> ==> /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log <==
>   ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-2.compute.internal:80 xx.78.xx.2xx - - 
>   [13/Sep/2017:18:40:44 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3509 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"

You'll notice that instead of xxx.xx.xx.xx:80 like a typical IP address 
I've got some FQDN like "ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-2.compute.internal:80"
I'm using AWS Elastic IP's to make a fixed IP for my Amazon EC2 web server.

**4. Check the head of your virtual-hosts .conf file**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 11.22.33.44:80>
# Added from nessus to make more secure
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
ServerName mydomain.com
...
```

OK so what we see here is we're telling Apache to serve this vhost for requests from 127.0.0.1 or 11.22.33.44 on port 80. But the server never sees these IPs as it get's that weird FQDN and so it never matches! Eureka!

**SOLUTION:**
Add *:80 to the VirtualHost tag so it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 11.22.33.44:80 *:80>
```

AND restart apache. I hope this helps. There may be other reasons but if this is the cause of your problem then it's time to sit back, have a cuppa tea and relax! If not then I hope you find the solution.

PS. Remember to put your logs back to warn rather than debug!

Comment: Using `<VirtualHost mysite.com:80 *:80>` and reloading Apache works like a charm. Thank you sir!

Comment: If you're putting `*:80`, anything else is just redundant. `<VirtualHost *:80>` will suffice.

Comment: For me, the problem was with the VirtualHost header, Fixed it like what you pointed and now works like a charm. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I ran through all of these solutions and none of them worked. Then, I decided to go back and check the apache2.conf file. I discovered that the line to include the "sites-enabled" conf files was commented out by default. By uncommenting the line and restarting apache, it fixed my problem (it was close to the end of the file):

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there is a problem with .conf files of the virtual-hosts.

First run the command:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

The response must be something like

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
     default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
     port 443 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
     port 443 namevhost myvhost.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myvhosts.com.conf:20)
             alias www.myvhost.com

*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost myvhost.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myvhost.com.conf:1)
             alias www.myvhost.com
```

But sometimes you can read:

```
default server myvhost.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
```

so your vhost domain point to default configuration (http or https).

The solution is to add `ServerName localhost` directive in the `default-ssl.conf` and in the `000-default.conf` files.

Apache don't know who is the name of your default site and it takes one random resolving 127.0.0.1.

After setting the ServerName, you must run:

```
service apache2 reload
service apache2 restart
```

If you run again `apache2ctl -S` you must see the correct match for the default server.

Answer (score 1):

it has been driving me nuts too, I have cheked my .conf files over and over again all was absolutely defined correctly. I ended up on this post tried the a2ensite and a2dissite commands as a sudoer, restarting apache, still landing on the default apache welcome page as if apache would have never disabled the default site or taken my new virtual host onboard.

It turns out I was trying to restart apache without using sudo...

```
service apache2 restart
```

use

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

if you keep default with *:80; *.443 make sure it is on the bottom - so rename 000-default to zzz-default

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when using a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) in the /etc/hosts file that is the same as a site I was trying to connect to. To solve this problem I had to rename the FQDN to something other than one of my VirtualHost ServerName values.

So in other words, if my /etc/hostname was:

```
apple
```

And in my /etc/hosts, I had:

```
192.168.54.34 apple.example.com apple
```

And in my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/apple.example.com.conf I had:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin blah@apple.example.com
    ServerName apple.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/apple.example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

apple.example.com would be accepted by the 000-default.conf because it is also listed in the /etc/hosts file. To solve this I just changed the FQDN of my server as follows in the /etc/hostname file:

```
server1
```

and /etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.54.34 server1.example.com server1
```

Answer (score 0):

This has bitten me more than once; sometimes I would enable with `sudo` - sometimes I would not.

Ubuntu 14.04 seems to display the same message either way.  When moving at 100 miles an hour, sometimes you miss a `sudo` or two.

The symptom of the new website defaulting back to wrong directory has been my only clue the the enabling never happened.  I'd say it's a bug.

It should at least warn when a command isn't executed!!!

Comment: BTW-- the same "bug" happens for a2dissite-- Ubuntu shows that it removed the symlinks-- but it actually did not.

Answer (score 0):

For me it started to work after restarting apache with: sudo service apache2 reload. And pressing ctrl + F5 on http:/test.

Answer (score 0):

My case on Apache 2.4 the issue was solved by adding below setting to virtual host configuration:

```
Listen 80
```

so that settings are something like:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName testsite.com
    ServerAlias www.testsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testsite
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

On my server default.conf was interfering with it since the filename of the virtual host conf file was alphabetically after it. I renamed default.conf to zdefault.conf and it works.