# Apache 2.4 virtual host ignored

Tags: apache, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I'm setting up a new web server using Ubuntu 14.0, following [the instructions here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) for creating virtual hosts, however my single additional virtual host always loads the default site (/var/www/html).

Here is my vhost configuration (I have replaced my domain with example.com, but it is otherwise identical):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/app

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have made NO OTHER CHANGES to the Apache 2.4 configuration which is installed in Ubuntu 14.

EDIT: I am correctly enabling sites and restarting apache after making changes to this vhost.

When I visit example.com in my browser, I get the default site. What am I doing wrong? How do I get this virtual host to load the correct directory?

EDIT: The solution is a missing "sudo" in the restart command (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23713299/225682).

Answer (score 2):

6 years too late but maybe this will help someone. When debugging issues like this, first check that apache can see your virtualhost configuration: `apachectl -S`

You should see your virtualhost configuration in the output:

```
*:80                   example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.com.conf:2)
```

If you cannot see it, maybe the config file path is not included into the main configuration file or the file itself is missing a .conf extension.

If you see your VirtualHost in the output but you're still getting the default VirtualHost instead, check the global `ServerName` directive in the main configuration file. It should NOT match your VirtualHost ServerName.

Beware - if your global ServerName is not set, apache will obtain one using rDNS. So if your IP address' reverse DNS record matches example.com (same as your VirtualHost), your VirtualHost might be ignored. I believe this is a very common source of problems and I haven't found this on the forums yet. Check your IP's rDNS record with `host` command if you face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to restart apache we server after you edit vhost, also you need to add enable vhost.
to enable:

```
sudo a2ensite example.conf (name of config file inside sites-available directory)
```

to restart server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

also check out permissions for www directory, maybe apache's user can't read that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Virtual hosts somewhere in your config?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: "AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release" - I thought it might work, but apparently this is automatic now.

Comment: Apache on Ubuntu is a bit of a pain to debug, because they've tried to make it idiot-proof. I don't have Ubuntu in front of me, but from what I recall in its distro of Apache 2, isn't there a sites-available and a sites-enabled directory, and your vhosts file should be in sites-enabled? I think that is what the a2ensite command does, but you might want to check that the file has actually been copied across.

Comment: The NameVirtualHost directive has no effect in Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23713299/225682.

Apache must be restarted with sudo, or the changes actually have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is my story. I had fresh install:

```
webmaster@ubuntuserver:/srv$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
webmaster@ubuntuserver:/srv$
webmaster@ubuntuserver:/srv$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-18T15:09:02
webmaster@ubuntuserver:/srv$
```

I used very simple virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@testsite.com
ServerName testsite.com
ServerAlias www.testsite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/testsite
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Tried many suggestions such as:

- directory permission settings;
- directory content chmod to 774;
- firewall settings;

Finally resolved with adding:

```
Listen 80
```

to the top of virtual host configuration, so it looks like:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName testsite.com
ServerAlias www.testsite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/testsite
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Eventually virtual hosts started responding and behaved as expected.

Interesting though, I later tried to recreate the issue and virtual hosts worked even without setting `Listen 80`. However I am sure the trigger which made virtual hosts to respond was `Listen 80` setting.

Anyway, you may also refer to Apache documentation:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: I have not found any dosumentation saying that you can add listen... to a vhost file. I get an error when doing that

Comment: @Gerfried, as per my example, I didn't add "Listen 80" inside "VirtualHost" directive, but on top. Even basic configuration example comes with "Listen 80":
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score -1):

Try running the apachectl command with the -t option, this checks all config is correct.  Which file is this virtual host.  Have you restarted apache to pickup these changes?

```
apachectl restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Everything checks out.

Comment: Try adding an entry in your /etc/hosts file, something like : 127.0.0.1     www.example.com, does this make any difference, looks like the request does not contain the host header info!

Comment: Tried that. Didn't change anything. Chrome inspector suggests the host header info is being sent, however.