# Getting error 404 not found with Flask running on Apache2

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a static website running on Apache2. I have a form on the website, and I want to pass on the contents of the form to a Flask app. Right now I only get error 404 when trying to pass the data to the app, but the static part of the site works fine.  I have configured it as follows:

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.



    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess mailer user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/mailer
    WSGIScriptAlias /mailer /var/www/mailer/app.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/mailer>
            WSGIProcessGroup mailer
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =alyfit.fi
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I initially had a separate .conf for the Flask app, but I read on another question here that you can't have the same servername and port for two different virtualhosts.

app.wsgi

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/apache2/mailer_error.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/mailer')
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/mailer/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/')
logging.debug('About to import app...')
from mailer import app as application
```

mailer.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, Blueprint
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
mailer_bp = Blueprint('mailer', __name__, url_prefix='/mailer')

# Flask-Mail configuration
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.redacted.com' 
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 1234 
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.getenv('MAIL_USERNAME') 
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.getenv('MAIL_PASSWORD') 
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False

mail = Mail(app)

@mailer_bp.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    email = request.form.get('email')

    msg = Message('Hello',
                  sender='redacted@redacted.com',
                  recipients=[email])
    msg.body = f'Hello {name}'
    mail.send(msg)

    return 'OK', 200

app.register_blueprint(mailer_bp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have tried so many different configurations and nothing seems to make it work. Nothing is being written on the mailer log, and Apache logs don't give any insight either. I have verified that all the necessary libraries are installed. I went through like 20 similar-ish stackoverflow questions and none of the solutions there worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create a new `.conf` file for your app and [disable your default.conf file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799865/4115031).  The default is just a fallback / placeholder, it's something to make it easy to tell that Apache is working when you first install it (because you can just open up your server's IP address in a browser and see the default Apache page).
2. You aren't actually setting the `ServerName` directive in your `.conf` file.  You should have lines in your `.conf` file that look something like this:

   ```
   ServerName your_domain.com
   ServerAlias www.your_domain.com
   ```
3. The `DocumentRoot` directive should be used to point to the folder where you have your app.  Normally you want your app in a subdirectory of `/var/www/`, so the directive should look something like this:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/<your_app_directory>
   ```